# A weird bug which only occurs in iPhone6Plus 8.2 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-6-plus, ios8.2

I'm against a weird bug which only occurs in iPhone6Plus iOS8.2 device.
The view sometimes blinks when I'm scrolling up and down.
It looks like a square magnifying glass. This only appears from top left corner.

I'm having this problem in UIScrollView and UIPanGestureRecognizer.
I've already tested 'iOS8.1 iPhone6Plus device', 'iOS8.2 iPhone6 device', 'iOS8.2 iPhone6Plus simulator' but it did not happen.

**This only occurs in iPhone6Plus iOS8.2 device.
Never happens in Simulator or any other devices. 
Neither in other iOS versions except iOS8.2.**

Does anyone have a guess whats going on? And how to solve this?

You can see the screen-movie from the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhlVSHjQBYw&feature=youtube_gdata

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you have turned on the `Magnification Option` in `Accessibility Settings`. This setting is not available on Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for answering but My iPhone's Magnification Option was disabled.

It looks more different than the Magnification thing.

Could you look at my youtube link and you'll know what I am trying to say.